# how to use the MVC in octobercms

Tags: model-view-controller, octobercms

i want to create an application octobercms
and for that I started to create **.htm** pages in a new theme
but I do not know how to handle the data from these pages

how to use MVC in octobercms

is it necessary to create a plugin for using model view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the answer to that is yes, you should create a plugin.

I highly recommend you use the excellent [Builder](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) plugin. This will give you a nice GUI for creating your plugin and will generate the basic required files. After using Builder to get the basics setup for you, it is easy to modify the files as needed.